# Shell script not working process just killing only 2 process apart from three process

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cron

Below script is not running via crontab. please let known what step do I need to fix this problem. This script runs fine when I trigger manually.

Crontab :-

```
### Repack Restart
33 01 * * 1,2,3,4,5  /home/repackpr/scripts/repack_restart_script.sh > /tmp/repack_log16234.log 2>&1
```

repack_restart_script.sh :

```
 #!/usr/bin/bash
    cd /home/repackpr
    today_date=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
    DATE_STAMP=`TZ=CST+24 date +%Y%m%d`

tomcat_pid=$(pgrep -U $USER java)
rmireg_pid=$(pgrep -U $USER rmiregistry)
nagios_pid=$(pgrep -U $USER nrpe)

export tomcat_pid
export rmireg_pid
export nagios_pid

    #Removing old logs

    rm /home/repackpr/scripts/Repack_$DATE_STAMP.log
    rm /home/repackpr/scripts/Repack_feed_mgt_$DATE_STAMP.log
    rm /home/repackpr/scripts/Repack_Stop_$DATE_STAMP.log

    # Stopping Services
    /home/repackpr/server stop
    kill -9 `ps -fu repackpr -o pid,comm | egrep 'java|repackpr' | awk '{print $1}'`
    /home/repackpr/server status > /home/repackpr/scripts/Repack_Stop_$today_date.log

    #Starting Services
    export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8071 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
    /home/repackpr/server start
    /home/repackpr/server status > /home/repackpr/scripts/Repack_$today_date.log

    VALUE=`grep up /home/repackpr/scripts/Repack_$today_date.log|wc -l`
    if [ $VALUE -eq 3 ]
    then
        /apps/repack/jetty/start.sh > /home/repackpr/scripts/Repack_feed_mgt_$today_date.log &  #####Starting Repack Feed Management######
        echo "Repack services has been started successfully"|mailx -s "Repack Service Restart--SUCCESS" rates-it_pune@xyz.com     else
        echo "Please perform the Repack service restart check" |mailx -s "Repack Service Restart--FAIL" rates-it_pune@list.xyz.com
    fi
```

server script :- this script is invoking from repack_restart_script.sh --> i.e /home/repackpr/server stop

```
#!/bin/bash
# 

wait-n-kill () {
    echo Waiting up to a minute for a graceful shutdown
    for(( i=0; $i<60; i=$(($i+1)) )); do
       sleep 1
       kill -0 $1 2>/dev/null || break
       echo -n .
    done
    echo
    kill -0 $1 2>/dev/null && echo Still alive ... Killing it with dash nine && kill -9 $1
}

tomcat_pid=$(pgrep -U $USER java)
rmireg_pid=$(pgrep -U $USER rmiregistry)
nagios_pid=$(pgrep -U $USER nrpe)

case "$1" in
      "start")
          if [ -z $tomcat_pid ] ; then
             suffix=$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M)
             echo Repack is not running. Creating rpdb.log.$suffix backup...
             cp /apps/repack/tomcat/webapps/rpdb/WEB-INF/fwk/log/rpdb.log /apps/repack/tomcat/webapps/rpdb/WEB-INF/fwk/log/rpdb.log.$suffix
             gzip /apps/repack/tomcat/webapps/rpdb/WEB-INF/fwk/log/rpdb.log.$suffix
             echo Starting Repack... This should start rmiregistry as well.
             $TOMCAT_EXE/startup.sh
          else
             echo Repack is already running
          fi
          if [ -f ~/monitoring/go.sh  ] ; then
             if [ -z $nagios_pid ] ; then
                echo Starting Nagios agent
                cd ~/monitoring && ./go.sh
             fi
          fi ;;
      "stop")
          if [ ! -z $tomcat_pid ] ; then
             echo Stopping Repack
             $TOMCAT_EXE/shutdown.sh
             wait-n-kill $tomcat_pid
          fi
          [ ! -z $rmireg_pid ] && echo Killing rmiregistry && kill $rmireg_pid && wait-n-kill $rmireg_pid
          [ ! -z $nagios_pid ] && echo Killing Nagios && kill $nagios_pid && wait-n-kill $nagios_pid
esac

tomcat_pid=$(pgrep -U $USER java)
rmireg_pid=$(pgrep -U $USER rmiregistry)
nagios_pid=$(pgrep -U $USER nrpe)

[ ! -z "$tomcat_pid" ] &&                               echo "Repack      is up ($tomcat_pid)" || echo "Repack      is down"
[ ! -z "$rmireg_pid" ] &&                               echo "rmiregistry is up ($rmireg_pid)" || echo "rmiregistry is down"
[ $REPACK_ENV = "PROD" ] && ( [ ! -z "$nagios_pid" ] && echo "Nagios      is up ($nagios_pid)" || echo "Nagios      is down" )
```

/tmp/repack_log16234.log

```
 pgrep: invalid user name -- java
        pgrep: invalid user name -- rmiregistry
        pgrep: invalid user name -- nrpe
        /home/repackpr/scripts/Repack_20160322.log: No such file or directory
        /home/repackpr/scripts/Repack_feed_mgt_20160322.log: No such file or directory
        pgrep: invalid user name -- java
        pgrep: invalid user name -- rmiregistry
        pgrep: invalid user name -- nrpe
        pgrep: invalid user name -- java
        pgrep: invalid user name -- rmiregistry
        pgrep: invalid user name -- nrpe
        Repack      is down
        rmiregistry is down
        /home/repackpr/server: line 54: [: =: unary operator expected
        pgrep: invalid user name -- java
        pgrep: invalid user name -- rmiregistry
        pgrep: invalid user name -- nrpe
        pgrep: invalid user name -- java
        pgrep: invalid user name -- rmiregistry
        pgrep: invalid user name -- nrpe
        /home/repackpr/server: line 54: [: =: unary operator expected
        pgrep: invalid user name -- java
        pgrep: invalid user name -- rmiregistry
        pgrep: invalid user name -- nrpe
        Repack is not running. Creating rpdb.log.20160323-0133 backup...
        Starting Repack... This should start rmiregistry as well.
        /home/repackpr/server: line 28: /startup.sh: No such file or directory
        Starting Nagios agent
        Nagios agent has been started
        pgrep: invalid user name -- java
        pgrep: invalid user name -- rmiregistry
        pgrep: invalid user name -- nrpe
        Repack      is down
        rmiregistry is down
        /home/repackpr/server: line 54: [: =: unary operator expected
        pgrep: invalid user name -- java
        pgrep: invalid user name -- rmiregistry
        pgrep: invalid user name -- nrpe
        pgrep: invalid user name -- java
        pgrep: invalid user name -- rmiregistry
        pgrep: invalid user name -- nrpe
        /home/repackpr/server: line 54: [: =: unary operator expected
```

Comment: This seems reasonable(ish). When you say "not running" do you mean that not even the `> /tmp/repack_log...` is not created? Please be more specific. Have you tried with `33 01 * * * /home/...` ? Good luck.

Comment: This question is probably best suited for Super User or Server Fault

Comment: Are you given execute permission for the script file and make sure that you added a shebang character `#!`

Comment: repack_log is generated but gets some error.                                           pgrep: invalid user name -- java
pgrep: invalid user name -- rmiregistry
pgrep: invalid user name -- nrpe
pgrep: invalid user name -- java
pgrep: invalid user name -- rmiregistry
pgrep: invalid user name -- nrpe
Repack      is down
rmiregistry is down
/home/repackpr/server: line 54: [: =: unary operator expected

Comment: I had used the shebang character  and I have this permission   -rwxr-xr-x   1 repackpr tdmatch     1526 Mar 15 01:30 repack_restart_script.sh

Comment: The Stack Overflow [`crontab` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) has a detailed list of troubleshooting steps.  Perform those, and update your question to show us what you did.

Comment: Can someone help on this error I am getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems with cron Jobs, which work differently from Jobs run from the command line, stem often from the fact, that the environment is set in a different way.

The error message indicates, that `pgrep` is invoked somewhere with an incorrect user name, maybe as a consequence from a missing environment variable. Since there is no `pgrep` in the code you are posting, I guess this is invoked in some script called from your cron job, which must be either `~repackpr/server` or `/apps/repack/jetty/start.sh`. Try to find, where `pgrep` is called, and work backwards from there.

Comment: Useful, but not an answer.  This should perhaps be a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
cron runs on a server defined timezone. You need to check out your sever timezone and then set your own cron. Assume your server timezone is GMT:

`33 01 * * 1-5 command-to-be-executed`

The cron format is below:

```
* * * * * 
| | | | | 
| | | | | 
| | | | +---- Day of the Week   (range: 1-7 or 0-6, 7/0 = Sunday)
| | | +------ Month of the Year (range: 1-12)
| | +-------- Day of the Month  (range: 1-31)
| +---------- Hour              (range: 0-23)
+------------ Minute            (range: 0-59)
```

Check more cron format examples [here](http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm)

Please provide more information about how often do you want to run the script by cron, then we can help to figure out what the output should be look like.

Comment: I want to run script at  1:33 GMT from mon - fri

Comment: Huh?  The year field is completely nonstandard. Which platform is this for?

Comment: Plat form is  Linux  3.0.101-0.47.52-default #1 SMP Thu Mar 26 10:55:49 UTC 2015 (0e3c7c8) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @haifzhan .cron is working fine now but I am getting error.can you help me on this.

Comment: @Ajinkya  1. `/home/repackpr/scripts/repack_restart_script.sh > /tmp/repack_log16234.log 2>&1`  change `>` to `>>` for redirecting your output, it will append the output to file other than truncate file and append; 2. check your default shell or execute `which shell` to get the path, for example `/bin/bash` and then put it in your cron.  `33 01 * * 1-5 /bin/bash /path/to/your/script  >> /tmp/repack_logxxx.lg 2>&1`